# gpg with powershell

Tags: powershell, gnupg

I used gnupg version 1.4 and this code in powershell to decrypt encrypted file worked fine:

```
echo mypassphrase | C:\gpg.exe --passphrase-fd 0 --output c:\list.xls --decrypt c:\gnupg\crypted\list.gpg
```

Now I've installed GNUPG2 and it doesn't work anymore. The only thing that changed is gpg.exe to gpg2.exe

When I run this command via command line it stucks here:

```
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "Marcel Seln (MS) <mseln@seln.sk>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID ED189121, created 2012-03-02 (main key ID 792EF596)
```

(only thing that helps is ctrl+c to interrupt command)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you running this in the PowerShell ISE?

Comment: Hi Joey, I've tried both command line and ISE. ISE didn't display that "You need a..." neither.

Comment: I was asking because the ISE doesn't support interactive console applications and it could have been that GPG tries to prompt the user for it (which would then fail).

Comment: I know, I primary work with command line, but I was desperate with this problem, so i've tried it in ISE too ;)

Comment: Is there some special reason you are using echo to put the passphrase on STDIN instead of just using the --passphrase option of GPG itself? This isn't more secure - maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Thank you Goyuix. I changed it to use the --passphrase option. There was no special reason for using echo, I just found it in the internet..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that this problem occures too, when I use GNU Privacy Assistent. It freezes and CPU consumption was at 100%. I don't know why this happens on my brand new Windows server 2003 virtual machine, but when I restarted it, everything works fine. There is no suspicious event in Event log.. 
Thank you for your time!